# jquery .children() selector: form in a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a simple html form:

```
<form action="/api/userattributes" method=get>
<select name=action>
<option>read_by_user</option>
<option>set</option>
<option>delete</option>
</select>
Attrib Name: <input name=name type=text size=20 value="">
Attrib Value: <input name=value type=text size=50 value="">
<br />
<input type=submit name="Go!">
</form>
```

And a simple jquery function that wants to touch some of the input fields in the form before they get submitted:

```
$(function()
{
    $("form").submit(function()
    {
        $(this).children(':input[value=""]').each(
            function() {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
        return true; // ensure form still submits
    });
});
```

That works fine.

But if I format the form with a table, my function no longer does anything.

Well, I thought, maybe the problem is that the children of the form are table elements (though that seems very weird), so I tried `.find()` instead of `.children()`, which again works with the vanilla version but not with the table version.

How do I find the form fields if my form is in a table?

Comment: Can you show the markup for the version that doesn't work?

Comment: "format a form with a table"..can you please clarify on this.?

Comment: The table formatting turned out to be slightly bad: <form><table>...</table></form> worked fine, but <table><form></table></form> failed. Live and learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you post your `table` code, as I made a guess at some table layout you would have used and had a working example pretty quickly. Embedded example below. jsFiddle [can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/3wCk9/).

```js
$(function()
{
    $("form").submit(function()
    {
        $(this).find('input[value=""]').each(
            function() {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
        return true; // ensure form still submits
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/api/userattributes" method="get">        
    <select name="action">
        <option>read_by_user</option>
        <option>set</option>
        <option>delete</option>
    </select>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Attrib Name:</td><td><input name="name" type="text" size="20" value="" /></td>
            <td>Attrib Value:</td><td><input name="value" type="text" size="50" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Go!" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Note I found two errors:

1. Your selector was `':input[value=""]'` and I changed that to `'input[value=""]'`
2. Need to use `find` rather than `children` as you suspected:

> Given a jQuery object that represents
> a set of DOM elements, the .children()
> method allows us to search through the
> immediate children of these elements
> in the DOM tree

Source: http://api.jquery.com/children/

**Edit:**

It sounds like you discovered your own solution, and I thought I'd better include it here for reference.

You were using:

```
<table>
  <form>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Whereas you should have switched the `<form>` and `<table>` around (as you did) so that the `<table>` was nested inside the `form`.

As you discovered, you can't have elements freely inside a `<table>` (everything must be in rows and columns). As a result, while it appears as though the rows and columns are sitting inside the `form`, it turns out they aren't actually nested inside it at all, and so aren't within the descendants that the `find` method searches.

Comment: Both HTML4 and HTML5 allow quotes around attributes to be omitted if the attribute value doesn't have spaces. XHTML would requires quotes, but he hasn't said he's using XHTML and from the format of the `input` tags, he isn't. (Although the `br` tags point the other way.)

Comment: I tried wrapping the attributes in quotes, no change. There was a close form tag in my code which I inadvertently left out here, edited to fix it.

Comment: +1 for your edit, `find` instead of `children` is *very* likely the solution.

Comment: @T.J Crowder - though the OP said they tried that without success. (Edit: Ah just realised the other thing I changed - a possibly bad selector)

Comment: Aha. If you aren't careful about the order of the form tag and the table tag it fails. Thanks, great answer.

Comment: Hi Dave, that could be because you can't have elements just inside the `<table>` that aren't in a `<td>`. So if you did `<table><form><tr><td>some element</td></tr></form></table>` I think you'd find the `<td>` isn't actually a child element of the `<form>`.

Comment: So if you have a table in which you need to put one form per row _but_ the fields span through many cells, you're just screwed. well done, HTML.